# Google Maps Pan and Zoom Customize Color

Tags: css, google-maps, zooming, customization, pan

I was wondering if it's possible to customize the pan and zoom color. From the default white color to something different or add gradients, maybe. I'm new with google maps and here's what I came up so far.

```
     function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.341908, 123.910602),
          zoom: 16,
          panControl: true,
          panControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
},


      zoomControl: true,
              zoomControlOptions: {
              style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);

       // Creating a marker and positioning it on the map    
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({    
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(10.341908, 123.910602),    
            map: map    
    });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

## map.gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint { put your css here}

```
#map .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint > div > img { display: none !important;}

#map .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Pan up"] { put your css here}

#map .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Pan down"] { put your css here }

#map .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Pan right"] { put your css here}

    #map .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Pan left"] {background:url(images/positionbutton_left.png) no-repeat center center !important; put your css here}

#map .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Zoom in"] {background:url(images/zoom_in.png) no-repeat center center !important; put your css here }

#map .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Zoom out"] {  put your css here }

        #map .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Drag to zoom"] { put your css here}
        
#map .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Click to zoom"] { put your css here}
```

Comment: This answer requires some clarification: where do you put the CSS, and why does this work?

Comment: Put it in any css file and add a reference at your mappage.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option implemented. But the controls finally are only images(sprites), it should be possible to change their `src` to a custom image in a different color once the map has finished loading.